# Minimum number of tested patients to have a reasonable ROC curve

Tags: classification, roc, reliability

What are the minimum number of tested patients and the acceptable prevalence percent required to have a reasonable ROC curve? for example, can I test a total of 16 patients, 5 are diseased and 11 are healthy? I mean by reasonable is how precise the curve will be depending only on 16 patients, 5 being diseased out of this number?

Comment: Define what precisely would make an ROC curve 'reasonable' or 'not reasonable'. A given sample size would be sufficient for some definitions and unsufficient for others.

Comment: Like @Glen_b, I have no idea what a "reasonable" ROC curve is, but I would not have a problem making one with your data. It just won't be a very precise estimate.

Answer (score 1):

An ROC curve plots the true positive rate as a function of the false positive rate. Assuming you're trying to detect the presence/absence of disease, you've only got up to 5 possible true positives and up to 11 possible false positives (fewer, if your classifier works well).

Although you could generate some sort of plot, the resulting curve is going to be very "blocky" and I would have fairly little confidence in any claims about the area under the curve (AUC).